# PHP WMI Query timeout

Tags: php, wmi

I am scanning a subnet to gather WMI information on assets on the network. However, if a machine is stuck in POST or has some unknown issue, it will freeze the script and never move on to the next machine. Question is, **is there a way to set a timeout on PHP COM WbemScripting.SWbemLocator?**

```
    $host = 10.1.1.5; //Host is online, but may be hung trying to shutdown

    //Check if host is online
    if(@$fp = fsockopen($host,135,$errCode,$errStr,0.1))
    {
        //Create new connection
        $WbemLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");

        //Connect to remote workstation
        $WbemServices = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\\cimv2',$user,$password);  
        $WbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;

        //Basic WMI query
        $system = $WbemServices->execQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");   

        foreach($pcsystem AS $n){

            $hostname = $n->Name; //Hostname

        }

        //Process all data ->Insert into DB
    }
//Move on to next machine. In this case, the script will never move on
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no - because it's a COM object, not a PHP object, and there's no facility to control this directly.

Longer, speculative answer, you could try tweaking the [TCP parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739819(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) via the registry notably TcpInitialRtt although there doesn't seem to be a lot of scope for changing the behaviour unless you are running on a very reliable and uncongested network. And you'll probably break other things running on the machine.